# Using Solr Spatial Search to find closest points to each other within close time range

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr

Scenario: I have a table with location records having a timestamp and a latlng field, I need to find closest points having a max distance of 100 meters between them within a time range of, say, 1 hour.

I've tried to index the latlng field with Solr's LatLonPointSpatialField and then doing some faceting on the timestamp field then taking each point of latlng and doing {!geofilt} with the point and of distance of 0.01, but as you can see this will be very slow since I've to take each point and try it with a range of timestamp. And all what I need to just to find closest points of latlng within a timestamp range. I don't know if there's a better way but I have the feeling that there's something in Solr that could help me out but I missed.

Comment: To make htis clear, I think I need to breakdown the problem into smaller ones.

First one is simply the need to find the closest points to each other from this multiple latlng records. Second one is to sort these based on timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to do is some sort of result clustering, Solr does have [a contrib](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/result-clustering.html) to do that, but I suspect it will not work out of the box. Maybe you could fork and customize it for you.

The more promising approach would be creating a [Streaming Expression](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/streaming-expressions.html) that does all you need. I am pretty confident you have all functions needed to build the whole thing.